# How do I move my navigation bar up so there is not so much space in between the top bar?

Tags: html, css, padding

Trying to move the main nav menu up so there isn't so much space in between the top bar. You can see our site here at http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/.

```
 <!-- Header Gray Band-->
        <?php endif; ?>   
      <!-- Start mainmenu -->
     <nav class="main_menu nav-home-four <?php if ( $ind_option['header_fixed'] ){?> stricky<?php } ?>">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-1 col-xs-20">
                    <div class="logo">
                    <?php 
                    $logo = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/site_transparent_logo.png';
                    if (isset($ind_option['site_transparent_logo']['url']) )
                    { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $ind_option['site_transparent_logo']['url'] ); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>" />
                        </a>
                    <?php } 
                    elseif ( $logo )
                    { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $logo ); ?>" title="<? php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"></a>
                    <?php
                    } 
                    else 
                    { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>    
                    <?php 
                    } 
                    ?>                      
                    </div>
                </div>          
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="nav-holder nav-menu pull-left text-left">
                        <div class="nav-t-holder pull-left text-left">
                            <div class="nav-header nav-t-header">
                                <button><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                            </div>
```

Comment: just remove the style **top: 70px;** from `.top-navigation-4 .main_menu {}`

Comment: What do you mean "in between the top bar"?

Comment: Thank you! you're a life saver! Do you also know how I can make the topbar stick with the main nav menu when scrolling?

Comment: @MercedesPennell Try position:sticky;

Comment: Trying to make the top nav bar stick while scrolling like the main nav does when scrolling, and need to add social media icons to the left of the top bar. Website is http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/ any help is greatly appreciated. :) 

i tried adding position: sticky but no luck.

Comment: @MercedesPennell If the original requirement was met, I would strongly recommend opening another question about the sticky nav instead of asking in the comments for more features.

Comment: @disinfor will do thanks